# Nested Foreach exiting after first loop - writing xml element

Tags: c#, xml, xmltextwriter

I am trying to create nested xml elements to look like below however the created file only contains the first element from `headingTags` and then the first foreach loop is exited. Why is this happening?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ProductProfile>
    <ProfileVersion>input</ProfileVersion>
        <ProductInformation>
            <ApplicableProducts>input</ApplicableProducts>
            <ProductDescription>input</ProductDescription>
        </ProductInformation>
        <CustomerInformation>
            <Name>input</Name>
        </CustomerInformation>
        <ProductionSettings>
            <LabelType>input</LabelType>
            <LabelQuantity>input</LabelQuantity>
            <Settings>
                <SettingsSRegisters>input</SettingsSRegisters>
            </Settings>
        </ProductionSettings>
        <PostProduction>
            <ActivationStatus>input</ActivationStatus>
        </PostProduction>
</ProductProfile>
```

This has only started happening since I added the line `tw.WriteEndElement();` after the first foreach. Without this line all of the end of elements were at the end of the file.

My code:

```
 Dictionary<string, int> tagNames = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"ProfileVersion", 0},
    {"ApplicableProducts", 1},
    {"ProductDescription", 1},
    {"Name", 2},
    {"LabelType", 3},
    {"LabelQuantity", 3},
    {"SettingsSRegisters", 4},
    {"ActivationStatus", 5}
};
    
public enum headingTags
{
    ProductProfile,     //0
    ProductInformation, //1
    CustomerInformation,//2
    ProductionSettings, //3
    Settings,           //4
    PostProduction      //5
}
public void SaveProfile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(path, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        tw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        // Opens the document  
        tw.WriteStartDocument();
        //tw.WriteComment("Configuration File");

        foreach (int headingValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(dataTags.headingTags)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Heading value does not match Tag name" + headingValue + " " );
            string headingString = Enum.GetName(typeof(dataTags.headingTags), headingValue);

            // Write heading element  
            tw.WriteStartElement(headingString);
            tw.WriteString(txtSettingsSRegisters.Text);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> dictLine in tagNames)
            {
                if (headingValue == dictLine.Value)
                {
                    tw.WriteStartElement(dictLine.Key, "");
                    tw.WriteString("TextBoxInput");
                    tw.WriteEndElement();
                    tw.WriteWhitespace("/n");
                }
                else
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("Heading value does not match Tag name" + headingValue + " " + dictLine.Value);
                }
            }
            //tw.WriteEndElement();
        }
        tw.WriteEndDocument();
        // close writer  
        tw.Close();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I added a try catch to find the exception being thrown `Error:Token StartElement in state Epilog would result in an invalid XML document.` and just added this line after the `foreach (int headingValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(dataTags.headingTags)))` to implement the correct format.

```
if (j != 0) { 
                            tw.WriteEndElement();
                        }
```

Comment: Ah I have fixed that typo now but when I include the line `tw.WriteEndElement();` it still exits the loop after the first element (`<ProductProfile>settings<ProfileVersion>TextBoxInput</ProfileVersion>
</ProductProfile>`)

Comment: Are there any exceptions being thrown?

Comment: None at all as it creates the file and writes the first element then the form just closes.

Comment: That was more of a hint than a question. It looked like a question, but I was being dishonest and hoping you would investigate the issue more thoroughly yourself. There is something happening that does throw an exception in there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out I should have thought to do that before posting. Added some try-catches to my code and found the exception `Error:Token StartElement in state Epilog would result in an invalid XML document.`. I will search around for fixes

Comment: I'd strongly advise against using `XmlWriter` directly. It's a very low level API and it's very easy to make mistakes (as you've found). Consider creating your document using the LINQ to XML model instead.

Comment: Hi Charles, I was trying to stick with c# as it is what I know but I will look into learning LINQ. I think I have found a way around it for now but if I run into more problems I will consider changing to LINQ instead.

Comment: @Ellak123 LINQ is part of C#, and has been since 2007. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/create-xml-trees) for an idea what the usage might look like.

Comment: Ah I see now.. thanks for the direction @CharlesMager